# When would `git branch --contains` return an empty string?

Tags: git

I'm using `git branch --contains` within a custom script on Jenkins to get the current branch name pointed to by `HEAD`.

Since `git branch --contains` returns a list where the current branch has an asterisk next to it, I can use that information along with some selection logic to get the branch name even while in a detached head state.

The problem is that occasionally, `git branch --contains` will return an empty string. This is happening after a `git clone` so the problem is not that the repo does not contain any commits. It also must be called from within a git repo or else the command would fail.

I cannot reproduce this locally so I'm wondering what would be the conditions for which `git branch --contains` returns an empty string?

Answer (score 1):

Branches are not the only form of ref name, and you don't need a name at all, you can make and refer to unnamed commits (for instance if you're just trying something quick or if you're prepping for a partial merge).

You can get a checkout without a branch name if you (clone and ask it to) check out a specific tag that isn't in any current upstream branch history, for instance. Or if you bypass checkout's convenience logic and check out a tracking ref directly, that'll (edit: also) get you a detached head that's likely not (yet) part of any local branch.

Comment: In that case, what would be your suggestion for getting the current branch name given a recent clone? If I just do a checkout on `HEAD` then I'm guaranteed to always be in a detached head state and the logic for branch selection would have to be adjusted. Note that this is a different question from "how to get the current branch name given a commit" as SO responses do not take into account a detached head state.

Comment: If you want to know an upstream's "current branch" name, ask it. `git ls-remote --symref origin HEAD` will feed you a `ref:` line showing what if any name `HEAD` is a stand-in for.